# Is there a consensus that cultural, erotic, social capital exists and can be bought with each other and economic capital?

Tags: society, economics, capitalism

Is there a **consensus** that cultural, erotic, social capital exists and can be bought with each other and economic capital?

This was the basis of the [great British class survey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_British_Class_Survey), and

> differing dimensions of social mobility can be classified in terms of
> differing types of capital that contribute to changes in mobility.
> Cultural capital, a term first coined by French sociologist Pierre
> Bourdieu distinguishes between the economic and cultural aspects of
> class. Bourdieu described three types of capital that place a person
> in a certain social category: economic capital; social capital; and
> cultural capital. Economic capital includes economic resources such as
> cash, credit, and other material assets. Social capital includes
> resources one achieves based on group membership, networks of
> influence, relationships and support from other people. Cultural
> capital is any advantage a person has that gives them a higher status
> in society, such as education, skills, or any other form of knowledge.

On the one hand, I would be reluctant to class someone as bourgeois on the grounds they were good at sex, e.g.. On the other, it does seem *reasonably true*. An easy solution is yes, but your "class" is determined by economic capital.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on "*On the other, it does seem reasonably true*", especially since you emphasize the qualifier "*reasonably*". The persuasiveness of that proposition would either weaken or reinforce the hypothesis of a consensus.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the impulse behind the question: 'bourgeois' is a word that to me is from history and has no current meaning. In the book *Caste*, the point is made that only the bottom and next to bottom levels are where the struggle happens. No one wants to lose ground and fall to the bottom caste. Mobility among higher levels might be impossible, but falling is. Since caste is basically an external judgement based on appearance, different kinds of capital have very little influence. The real problem is not with things and processes, but with people's minds.

Answer (score 2):

There's definitely no such consensus.

Modern capitalist societies are founded on economic capital, and other forms of capital are all translated into economic terms, but that isn't universal. For instance, the British aristocracy traditionally assigns status on birth and "breeding"--wealth is secondary. In ancient China, cultural and educational capital was primary, wealth and status was a consequence of education. In "gift" economies, status is built from what you can give, not from what you can acquire.

So there's also no single answer to your question. Different cultures and societies have different ways of building and exchanging capital, as well as different forms of capital that they recognize.

Comment: i see what you mean, but the fact that in some places some forms of social capital cannot be bought does not really suggest that there's no consensus that social capital can be bought (and traded in for economic capital)

Comment: Consensus means "everyone agrees" and I don't see any evidence for that.  Who are you perceiving a consensus among?